# Google maps api v3 standard cursors

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to set cursor. 
Google documentaion quote:

> setCursor(cursor:string)

And that's all. What string should I enter? Can't  find list of available cursors.

Comment: Hey, there. Did my answer (most-voted on one below) fix the issue for you?

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you're looking at a method for the google.maps.Marker class. I think instead that you want to change an option on the map itself. Here's an example:

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
```

You can set it to `null` to return it to the default. I'll make a guess and say that the value can be any CSS cursor property. You may even be able to specify a url.

Comment: It's some time later, but I just thought I'd say that setting `draggableCursor` to `null` worked for me also when trying to return to the default open-hand cursor. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I suspect that the available values for cursors are the standard CSS cursors, which can be find here on the w3c website:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you can access Googles own cursors, when I use it I only enter a path to an icon on my own server ie `"\img\icon.png"`.